# Clang format splits if statement body into multiple lines

Tags: c++, formatting, clang, clang-format

I have the following .cpp file:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void call_long_function_name(bool) {}
void sf(bool) {}
int main() {
  bool test = true;
  if (test) { call_function_name(test); }
  if (test) { sf(test); }
  return 0;
}
```

(the slashes delimit 80 characters). Using the following configuration file, clang-format suggests:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void call_long_function_name(bool) {}
void sf(bool) {}
int main() {
  bool test = true;
  if (test) { 
    call_function_name(test); 
  }
  if (test) { 
    sf(test); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

even tho in the file I allow short if statements to fit into a single line.

- Did I set any options wrong?
- Which options can I use to minimize wasted vertical space?

Clang-format's .clang-format file

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
AccessModifierOffset: -1
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
ColumnLimit: 80
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 0
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerBinding: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: true
IndentWidth: 2
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
PointerBindsToType: true
SpaceAfterControlStatementKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInAngles:  false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 2
UseTab: Never
```

Comment: there is not a clang-format tag yet, I'd appreciate if someone could add it.

Comment: The problem is the brackets. `if (test) call_function_name(test);` However, what makes you think that that vertical space is wasted? Is vertical space a precious resource that needs to be conserved? It's not. BTW, good luck putting a break point in the debugger at that `call_function_name(test)` statement if it's on the same line as the `if`.

Comment: @DavidHammen yes, it seems that the problem is in the brackets. Do you put breakpoints using line numbers? I never do :/

Comment: @DavidHammen: vertical space *is* a precious resource, the more I can see without moving the page up and down, the easier it is to understand a piece (or multiple pieces) of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Newer versions of clang-format have an additional option "AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine", which controls this behavior.

Comment: I've marked this as answer since it is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that `clang-format` only applies the `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` option if you omit the brackets.  I tested the following:

```
void call_long_function_name(bool) {}
void call_long_super_duper_long_really_really_long_way_long_function_name(bool) {}
void sf(bool) {}
int main() {
  bool test = true;
  if (test) 
    call_function_name(test);
  if (test)
    sf(test);
  if (test)
    call_long_super_duper_long_really_really_long_way_long_function_name(test);
  if (test) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And got:

```
void call_long_function_name(bool) {}
void call_long_super_duper_long_really_really_long_way_long_function_name(
bool) {}
void sf(bool) {}
int main() {
  bool test = true;
  if (test) call_function_name(test);
  if (test) sf(test);
  if (test)
    call_long_super_duper_long_really_really_long_way_long_function_name(test);
  if (test) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I suppose that a patch could be submitted so that instead of determining if there is a single statement behind the `if`, clang-format would determine whether it's a single statement in a block, or not. Might be slightly more difficult of course.

Comment: @MatthieuM. im updating my trunk to check if this still happens with the latest trunk version (clang-format is a very active project). If that is the case I'll submit a bug report and post it here.